# How can I get a user id via soundcloud api call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to get a user's id, with resolve so I used this code, yet I keep getting an error in node js saying the object is not a function... please help, thanks. :\ much love <3

```
SC.get('/resolve', {URL: 'https://soundcloud.com/randomsoundclouduser'
}, function (user) {
    console.log(user_id);
});
```

...of course "randomsoundclouduser" is and will be a real username on Soundcloud.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slightly wrong.

URL was capital. 
Use user.id and not user_id

That should work:

```
SC.get('/resolve', {url: 'https://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou'}, function (user) {
console.log(user.id);
});
```

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/1LnxaL1s/

Comment: Thank you for your response! :)....so I copied and pasted your version of the code and i received the same error saying, "object is not a function"       :\

Comment: On jsfiddle it works. I guess i need more code to solve this.

Comment: Yesh, its weird...like just about every api call i put in my code gets an undefined for some parameter....or it says object is not a function once I think i wrote it correct. :\       my pc might be cursed...

Comment: also, can you use the code with '#result" (from your fiddle) in nodejs?

Comment: dont know, i am not that familar with nodejs. just remove the jquery stuff, that was for easy demo purpose - to show the result in a div, not the console. may be its worth to take a look on that module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soundclouder